# Collaboration on various ideas

Tags: system-agnostic

This may even be exactly the place that I'm looking for, still learning to navigate the site and kind of its purpose. But is there a forum area where people can discuss their own ideas for campaign settings and more in an open seminar format than a Q&A specific fashion? For instance just share stories about what kinds of campaigns and adventures they have run, what sorts of cool world ideas they've implemented and possibly even find others with similar interests to bring into your group (or join their group if they have one)?

Comment: While we're not a community specifically focused on campaign ideas, and it's not a forum, I'd like to mention we already get some of that stuff done in the [chat]. Feel free to drop by!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a forum. But, do try the chat room!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because questions about site functionality belong on the [site meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

I do believe there are a couple reddit forums that cater to Story collaboration, in addition to a few for putting a group together. Though notably, I can only speak for pathfinder and DnD  in particular as those are the two I play.

These are the ones I follow, though there are many others:

http://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/

http://www.reddit.com/r/3d6/

http://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/